# Check for RGB in one command instead of color.red color.blue color.green

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I have a script that's checking RGB values of a PNG file pixel by pixel

what I'm trying to figure out is instead of using this code (Bad Code)

```
Debug.Log(Color.red + Color.green + Color.blue);
```

this code returns this to the log

```
 RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)RGBA(0.000, 1.000, 0.000, 1.000)RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000)
```

---

Fixed Code

```
Color32 currentPixel = mapImage.GetPixel(x, z);
Debug.Log(currentPixel);
```

---

as you can see its already checking rgb each time but only looking for the red, green and blue from the codes Color.red and so on commands

can you do the same thing but have the debug.log return

```
RGBA(255, 255, 255, 255)
```

EDIT2---Code Now Works-------------

this is the entire code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;


public class CustomWindow : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Window/My Custom Window")]
    static void ShowWindow()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(CustomWindow));
    }

    void OnInspectorUpdate()
    {
        Repaint();
    }

    Texture2D mapImage = null;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        mapImage = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Map to render", mapImage,     typeof(Texture2D), true) as Texture2D;
        if (mapImage != null)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Add to scene"))
            {
                int width = mapImage.width;
                int height = 1;
                int depth = mapImage.height;

                for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        //Something to detect what color the pixel is at     position x, z
                        //and tell what gameobject to place depending on     what color was chosen
                        //bool isWall = mazeImage.GetPixel(x, z).r < 0.5;     //example code snippet from Cubiquity ColoredCubeMazeFromImage.cs
                        //mazeImage.GetPixel(x, z).r < 0.5;

                        Color32 currentPixel = mapImage.GetPixel(x, z);
                        Debug.Log("X:" + x + " Z:" + z + "/ Width:" + width     + " Depth:" + depth + " / " + currentPixel);

                        // THIS IS THE LINE I NEED TO EDIT TO SHOW THE     VALUES OF RGB FROM THE SCAN ABOVE
                        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText("G:/Save/RGB.txt",     Color.red);


                        for (int y = height - 1; y > 0; y--)
                        {
                            //Nothing for now but possibly
                            //if color of x, z = thisColor
                            //Place thisGameObject 1 tile above thisColor
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're outputting the values of constants, with the formatting defined by the `Color` class - you're not actually looking at the r/g/b value of any given pixel. The float values of the rgba channels for a given instance of a `Color` are in the `r`, `g`, `b`, and `a` fields, respectively. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html

Comment: I dont know Unity. Skipped through the ScriptReference really quick. I honestly dont know how the code above can produce this result. Since the + operator is overloaded and statements in parenthesis are executed first, it doesnt make sense it calls ToString before adding the colors together. Are you sure this is the code that produced the log you provided?

Comment: is there a way to check the value of the current pixel?

Comment: I'm new to programming so I'm still in the dark about a lot, the + in debug.log just adds the next parameter to the log

Preston Guillot is right tho, it was just printing what color I had in the code ex. color.red = 1,0,0,1 always and not what pixel the code was scanning

Comment: Not sure what you mean by current pixel. As i said i dont know Unity but if you have a png file you probably have a Texture2D. It seems you can querry the pixel values with Texture2D.GetPixel. Be sure to check out the Unity ScriptReference. It seems to be very good:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html

Comment: Ill post the whole code fora better example

Comment: @NathanRadtke Like I said, the rgba values of a given instance of a `Color` are in fields of the same name, assuming your have an instance of  `Color` in a variable named, for instance, `myColor`, the red channel value is accessible at `myColor.r`, the blue at `myColor.b`, etc. You aren't showing enough code here to diagnose what you're *actually* doing, but from what you *are* showing you're looking at static values of the `Color` class representing absolute red, blue, and green, rather than any pixel's color.

Comment: Try Color32 constructor, e.g new Color32(rgb). http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-ctor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only printing constants. To get the pixel from your image you have to use the GetPixel function:

```
Color currentPixel = mapImage.GetPixel(x, z);
 Debug.Log("X:" + x + " Z:" + z + "/ Width:" + width + " Depth:" + depth + " / " + currentPixel);
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html

Just to clarify, the reason your code did not work is that you where not actually addressing your image. If you write Color.red, Color.green etc. you get constants, which store rgb values for a specific color.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html

As you can see in the ScriptReference, these colors are statically defined. They have nothing to do with your particular image.

And another note to the "+" symbol. The first code does not produce the log you provided. In unity Colors have the "+" operator overloaded. This means you can actually add Colors together(mathematically). So i expected to see the colors added together in your log. The reason your log is different is because you had a string in front of that. The code gets executed from left to right. So the colors will be converted to strings first and then get added.

Comment: Yea I figured out I was printing constants once you pointed it out, like I said I'm new to this so a lot gets over my head still.  Thanks that code works and now the Script Reference for it makes sense to me